# Redirecionamento para tela "Home" após validar login - React Native + Firebase

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, react-router, react-navigation

Preciso implementar no código abaixo o comando para assim que o usuário for validado seja redirecionado para a tela “Home”.
As alterações que fiz não resolveram meu problema. 
Consigo criar o usuário, salvar no Firebase mas quando faço login não consigo direcionar para tela “Home”.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';
import Login from './screens/Login';
import Register from './screens/Register';
import ForgotPassword from './screens/ForgotPassword';
import { w } from './api/Dimensions';
import Home from './screens/Home';

export default class FirebaseLogin extends Component {
  state = {
    currentScreen: 'login', // can be: 'login' or 'register' or 'forgot'
  };

  changeScreen = screenName  => () => {
    this.setState({ currentScreen: screenName  });
  };

  userSuccessfullyLoggedIn = user => {
    this.props.login(user);
  };

  render() {
    let screenToShow;

    switch (this.state.currentScreen) {
      case 'login':
        screenToShow = (
          <Login
            change={this.changeScreen}
            success={this.userSuccessfullyLoggedIn}
          />
        );
        break;
      case 'register':
        screenToShow = <Register change={this.changeScreen} />;
        break;
      case 'forgot':
        screenToShow = <ForgotPassword change={this.changeScreen} />;
        break;
    }

    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior="position"
        keyboardVerticalOffset={-w(40)}
        style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={this.props.background}
          style={styles.background}
          resizeMode="stretch">
          {screenToShow}
        </ImageBackground>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

FirebaseLogin.propTypes = {
  login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

FirebaseLogin.defaultProps = {
  background: null,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta isso, como dá pra ver ele fica observando se algum usuário autenticou, e entao redireciona. Era essa sua dúvida?

```
componentDidMount() {
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user != null) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
  }
})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Junto da função de Login do button 'Entrar' eu repasso o onAuthStateChanged.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // Redirecionamento de tela.
  }
});
```